# I'm trying to update a pipeline variable in azure devops with another variable. But I'm not sure how to do this exactly

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-api-apps

I am reading a value from .json file and storing it in a variable. Then updating this value to the pipeline variable.

```
$data = (Get-content -Path("C:/Desktop/file.json")).androidVersionName |Out-String
```

In the above cmd, I'm reading the data of androidVersionName from file.son and converting it to string data type

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.setVariable variable=version;]$data"
```

In the above cmd, I'm setting the value of pipeline variable version to the value available in data. But the value is not getting updated in powershell task of azure. Pls some one help. I'm trying this for release pipeline CD

Tried different methods suggested in comments section. Not sure why it is not getting updated in the pipeline variable section. Will there be any problem related to access? Or will it work if I add variable groups and use that?

Comment: Have you read through **Set variables in scripts** from the Microsoft Website?  <https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/set-variables-scripts?view=azure-devops&tabs=powershell>

Answer (score 1):

Can you check this line?

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.setVariable.variable=version;]data"
```

According to the documentation, you should use `task.setVariable variable=version` instead of `task.setVariable.variable=version`: [Set variables in scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-variables-in-scripts)

Examples:

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=sauce]crushed tomatoes"
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=secret.Sauce;issecret=true]crushed tomatoes with garlic"
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=myOutputVar;isOutput=true]this is the value"
```

Additionally, check your `Get-Content`, you should convert your json string..... as example

```
$data = Get-content -Path "C:/Desktop/file.json" | ConvertFrom-Json
$version = $data.androidVersionName

Write-Host "##vso[task.setVariable variable=version]$version"
```

Comment: Yes sorry. My bad. Did that as well. Still not able to update

Comment: @Mitsuhaki, check your file reading, I`ve updated my answer.

Comment: Tried this as well @Shamrai Aleksander. Still no luck. Will there be any issue related to access? Or can I use variable groups to overcome this issue?

Comment: @Mitsuhaki, can you share the content of C:/Desktop/file.json?

Comment: "androidVersionName" : "12.5" - this is the only text that is present In that json.

Comment: @Mitsuhaki, that's not a json format. You have to use `{"androidVersionName" : "12.5"}`. In your case, you'll receive the exception: `ConvertFrom-Json : Invalid JSON primitive:  "12.5"`.

Answer (score 0):

echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=myvar]Get-content -Path("C:/Desktop/file.json").androidVersionName |Out-String" --> tried this code and it worked like a charm